# devise no longer working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have recently noticed when deploying my app to heroku that the devise gem seems to be causing me some grief due to the ruby version. I have tried lowering the devise version 3.9 but this still didn't fix it

```
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Using rake 11.1.2
       Installing aasm 4.10.0
       Using i18n 0.7.0
       Using json 1.8.3
       Using minitest 5.8.4
       Using thread_safe 0.3.5
       Using builder 3.2.2
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
       Using rack 1.6.4
       Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
       Using arel 6.0.3
       Using execjs 2.6.0
       Using bcrypt 3.1.11
       Using tilt 2.0.2
       Using highline 1.7.8
       Using sexp_processor 4.7.0
       Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
       Using sass 3.4.22
       Using temple 0.7.6
       Using terminal-table 1.5.2
       Using cancancan 1.13.1
       Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
       Using dalli 2.7.6
       Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing geocoder 1.3.4
       Using jwt 1.5.4
       Using kgio 2.10.0
       Using memcachier 0.0.2
       Using multi_json 1.11.2
       Using pg 0.18.4
       Installing puma 3.4.0 with native extensions
       Using bundler 1.11.2
       Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Using rolify 5.1.0
       Using tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing braintree 2.60.0
       Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
       Using rack-test 0.6.3
       Using warden 1.2.6
       Using mime-types 3.0
       Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6
       Using uglifier 3.0.0
       Using haml 4.0.7
       Using ruby_parser 3.8.1
       Using slim 3.0.6
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing sprockets 3.6.0
       Using twilio-ruby 4.11.1
       Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
       Using activesupport 4.2.4
       Using loofah 2.0.3
       Using mail 2.6.4
       Using material_design_lite-sass 1.1.3
       Using ruby2ruby 2.3.0
       Using html2haml 2.0.0
       Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using globalid 0.3.6
       Using activemerchant 1.58.0
       Using activemodel 4.2.4
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using brakeman 3.2.1
       Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
       Using activejob 4.2.4
       Using activerecord 4.2.4
       Using actionview 4.2.4
       Using friendly_id 5.1.0
       Using pg_search 1.0.5
       Using actionpack 4.2.4
       Using actionmailer 4.2.4
       Using railties 4.2.4
       Using kaminari 0.16.3
       Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
       Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
       Using responders 2.1.2
       Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
       Using rails 4.2.4
       Using sass-rails 5.0.4
       Installing devise 4.0.0
       Gem::InstallError: devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
       An error occurred while installing devise (4.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install devise -v '4.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Using rake 11.1.2
       Installing aasm 4.10.0
       Using i18n 0.7.0
       Using json 1.8.3
       Using minitest 5.8.4
       Using thread_safe 0.3.5
       Using builder 3.2.2
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
       Using rack 1.6.4
       Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
       Using arel 6.0.3
       Using execjs 2.6.0
       Using bcrypt 3.1.11
       Using tilt 2.0.2
       Using highline 1.7.8
       Using sexp_processor 4.7.0
       Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
       Using sass 3.4.22
       Using temple 0.7.6
       Using terminal-table 1.5.2
       Using cancancan 1.13.1
       Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
       Using dalli 2.7.6
       Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing geocoder 1.3.4
       Using jwt 1.5.4
       Using kgio 2.10.0
       Using memcachier 0.0.2
       Using multi_json 1.11.2
       Using pg 0.18.4
       Installing puma 3.4.0 with native extensions
       Using bundler 1.11.2
       Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Using rolify 5.1.0
       Using tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing braintree 2.60.0
       Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
       Using rack-test 0.6.3
       Using warden 1.2.6
       Using mime-types 3.0
       Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6
       Using uglifier 3.0.0
       Using haml 4.0.7
       Using ruby_parser 3.8.1
       Using slim 3.0.6
       Using coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing sprockets 3.6.0
       Using twilio-ruby 4.11.1
       Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
       Using activesupport 4.2.4
       Using loofah 2.0.3
       Using mail 2.6.4
       Using material_design_lite-sass 1.1.3
       Using ruby2ruby 2.3.0
       Using html2haml 2.0.0
       Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using globalid 0.3.6
       Using activemerchant 1.58.0
       Using activemodel 4.2.4
       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Using brakeman 3.2.1
       Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
       Using activejob 4.2.4
       Using activerecord 4.2.4
       Using actionview 4.2.4
       Using friendly_id 5.1.0
       Using pg_search 1.0.5
       Using actionpack 4.2.4
       Using actionmailer 4.2.4
       Using railties 4.2.4
       Using kaminari 0.16.3
       Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
       Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
       Using responders 2.1.2
       Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
       Using rails 4.2.4
       Using sass-rails 5.0.4
       Installing devise 4.0.0

       Gem::InstallError: devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
       An error occurred while installing devise (4.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install devise -v '4.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: It says `devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0` Did you tried upgrading the Ruby to 2.1?

Comment: how do i do this via heroku

Comment: Do you have the same issue in local?

Comment: no, the issue is only when i attempt to deploy to heroku

Comment: Try updating your Ruby to 2.1 in local and push it.

Comment: You can specify the ruby in your Gemfile, or better yet set an environment variable in your heroku app config: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: cheers @JanBussieck that resolved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the ruby in your Gemfile, or better yet set an environment variable in your heroku app config: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions